# Set width and height for modal angular 4

Tags: angular, angular6

In my modal width and height is applying all modal but i want apply only what i have opened modal.
If you see my code easily understand.

This is my code:

```
<app [(visible)]="test" [height]="height" [width]="width"> 
</app>
<app2 [(visible)]="test2" [height]="height" [width]="width"> 
</app2>
```

I am trying to set width and height and title only what i have opened popup modal not all popup.

Open popup and check in inspect element for two popup's height and width and title.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple workaround, you can set the app modal size with the help of CSS. Use a parent holder element with unique CSS to modify the style of the

```
<div class="app1-style"> <app [(visible)]="test"></app> </div>
<div class="app2-style"> <app [(visible)]="test"></app> </div>
```

Comment: @AppleOrange yes I can. Pass me the ref

Comment: Gopi Nath:See my Question I have updated stackblitz. Pls edit it.

Comment: Sure. Give me 10 mins.

Comment: Thank you so much Gopi Nath: Really very nice

Comment: Gopi: I have more doubt in angular 6. How can i post my question to you..If it not possible Or can you give me your mail id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178250/discussion-between-sujeith-gopi-nath-and-apple-orange).